# Negative number binary and change LSB of it

Tags: c#, image-processing, watermark

Sir I have a problem.I find the binary of a negative number that gives me in 32 bits.I trim all other bits except the first 8 bits.Now I change LSB of it.It gives me 125 as answer. I have to embed this in an gray scale image. According to my requirement , I have to add this 125 in mean(sum of four neighbouring pixels) .When i add this to mean.I gives me answer that exceeds 255. So is it posible that after modifing lsb. my bit remain negative.

here is my code

```
string str1 = Convert.ToString(d[1, 1], 2);
str1 = str1.Substring(Math.Max(str1.Length - 8, 0)).PadLeft(8, '0');
char[] data = new char[str1.Length]; 

for (int m = 0; m < str1.Length; m++)
{
    data[m] = str1[m];
}

//data[0] = '0';
string s="";
data[0] = '0';

for (int m = 0; m < str1.Length; m++)
{
    s += data[m];
}

byte output = Convert.ToByte(s, 2);
```

Comment: Binary operations involving `Convert.ToString(..., 2);` make me sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trimming all but the *last* 8 bits. If you want to trim all but the *first* 8 bits, you should use str1.Substring(0, 8). And you are changing the MSB of the last 8 bits. if you want to change the LSB, you should use data[7] instead of data[0].

Comment: @Ehsan I have to agree with the comment, though, this is a very inefficient way of doing bitwise operations. If you want to clear the lowest bit of a number, it's much faster to use `d[1,1] &= ~1`;